# Using DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 in Cloud Build from GCP

Tags: docker, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

My problem is that I am trying to use Cloud Build with a repository containing a Dockerfile that needs to use the Docker BuildKit to be generated correctly, but Cloud Build does not allow its use, here the code:

```
# Stage 1 - Create yarn install skeleton layer
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim AS packages

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

COPY packages packages

# Comment this out if you don't have any internal plugins
COPY plugins plugins

RUN find packages \! -name "package.json" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -exec rm -rf {} \+

# Stage 2 - Install dependencies and build packages
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim AS build

# install sqlite3 dependencies
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsqlite3-dev python3 build-essential && \
    yarn config set python /usr/bin/python3

USER node
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=packages --chown=node:node /app .

# Stop cypress from downloading it's massive binary.
ENV CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=0
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.cache/yarn,sharing=locked,uid=1000,gid=1000 \
    yarn install --frozen-lockfile --network-timeout 600000

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN yarn tsc
RUN yarn --cwd packages/backend build
# If you have not yet migrated to package roles, use the following command instead:
# RUN yarn --cwd packages/backend backstage-cli backend:bundle --build-dependencies

RUN mkdir packages/backend/dist/skeleton packages/backend/dist/bundle \
    && tar xzf packages/backend/dist/skeleton.tar.gz -C packages/backend/dist/skeleton \
    && tar xzf packages/backend/dist/bundle.tar.gz -C packages/backend/dist/bundle

# Stage 3 - Build the actual backend image and install production dependencies
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim

# Install sqlite3 dependencies. You can skip this if you don't use sqlite3 in the image,
# in which case you should also move better-sqlite3 to "devDependencies" in package.json.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsqlite3-dev wget python3 build-essential && \
    yarn config set python /usr/bin/python3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install mkdocs-techdocs-core==1.0.1

# From here on we use the least-privileged `node` user to run the backend.
USER node

# This should create the app dir as `node`.
# If it is instead created as `root` then the `tar` command below will fail: `can't create directory 'packages/': Permission denied`.
# If this occurs, then ensure BuildKit is enabled (`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`) so the app dir is correctly created as `node`.
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the install dependencies from the build stage and context
COPY --from=build --chown=node:node /app/yarn.lock /app/package.json /app/packages/backend/dist/skeleton/ ./

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.cache/yarn,sharing=locked,uid=1000,gid=1000 \
    yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production --network-timeout 600000

# Copy the built packages from the build stage
COPY --from=build --chown=node:node /app/packages/backend/dist/bundle/ ./

# Copy any other files that we need at runtime
COPY --chown=node:node app-config.yaml ./

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
RUN chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy

# This switches many Node.js dependencies to production mode.
ENV NODE_ENV production
ADD start.sh credentials.json ./
COPY catalog ./
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

I tried to modify the code using artificial intelligence as I'm not very good at docker but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the buildkit `--mount` options are mainly there for performance and you should be able to remove them and still be able to build.

Try

```
# Stage 1 - Create yarn install skeleton layer
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim AS packages

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

COPY packages packages

# Comment this out if you don't have any internal plugins
COPY plugins plugins

RUN find packages \! -name "package.json" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -exec rm -rf {} \+

# Stage 2 - Install dependencies and build packages
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim AS build

# install sqlite3 dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsqlite3-dev python3 build-essential && \
    yarn config set python /usr/bin/python3

USER node
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=packages --chown=node:node /app .

# Stop cypress from downloading it's massive binary.
ENV CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=0
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --network-timeout 600000

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN yarn tsc
RUN yarn --cwd packages/backend build
# If you have not yet migrated to package roles, use the following command instead:
# RUN yarn --cwd packages/backend backstage-cli backend:bundle --build-dependencies

RUN mkdir packages/backend/dist/skeleton packages/backend/dist/bundle \
    && tar xzf packages/backend/dist/skeleton.tar.gz -C packages/backend/dist/skeleton \
    && tar xzf packages/backend/dist/bundle.tar.gz -C packages/backend/dist/bundle

# Stage 3 - Build the actual backend image and install production dependencies
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim

# Install sqlite3 dependencies. You can skip this if you don't use sqlite3 in the image,
# in which case you should also move better-sqlite3 to "devDependencies" in package.json.
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsqlite3-dev wget python3 build-essential && \
    yarn config set python /usr/bin/python3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install mkdocs-techdocs-core==1.0.1

# From here on we use the least-privileged `node` user to run the backend.
USER node

# This should create the app dir as `node`.
# If it is instead created as `root` then the `tar` command below will fail: `can't create directory 'packages/': Permission denied`.
# If this occurs, then ensure BuildKit is enabled (`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`) so the app dir is correctly created as `node`.
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the install dependencies from the build stage and context
COPY --from=build --chown=node:node /app/yarn.lock /app/package.json /app/packages/backend/dist/skeleton/ ./

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production --network-timeout 600000

# Copy the built packages from the build stage
COPY --from=build --chown=node:node /app/packages/backend/dist/bundle/ ./

# Copy any other files that we need at runtime
COPY --chown=node:node app-config.yaml ./

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
RUN chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy

# This switches many Node.js dependencies to production mode.
ENV NODE_ENV production
ADD start.sh credentials.json ./
COPY catalog ./
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

Comment: I have tried and I get these errors, thanks for trying to help me.
https://imgur.com/a/aRVpdXy